# How does the While statement works in JS?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I'm learning JS in codecademy and it is going very well so far.

But on a particular exercise, there's a step which I can't understand. I solved it and ticked all the 3 exercise steps but the outcome is not what I expected so I was wondering if anybody can help me out?

I'm putting every step of the exercise and then what I've done.

In the end, I'll put what the console logged.

### 1.
Below the cards array, declare a variable, currentCard, with the let keyword but don't assign it a value.

```
const cards = ['diamond', 'spade', 'heart', 'club'];

// Write your code below
let currentCard;
```

### 2.
Create a while loop with a condition that checks if the currentCard does not have that value 'spade'.

Inside the block of your while loop, add the following line of code:

### currentCard = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];

### Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) will give us a random number from 0 to 3. 

We'll use this number to index the cards array, and assign the value of currentCard to a random element from that array.

```
const cards = ['diamond', 'spade', 'heart', 'club'];

// Write your code below
let currentCard;

while ( currentCard != 'spade') {  
  currentCard = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];  
}
```

### 3.
Awesome! Your loop is running, but you can't tell because it doesn't output anything. Let's add a console.log() statement to our while block. Inside the block, after you assign currentCard a new value, log currentCard to the console.

### For fun you can run your code a few times and see how the output changes!

```
const cards = ['diamond', 'spade', 'heart', 'club'];

// Write your code below
let currentCard;

while ( currentCard != 'spade') {
  currentCard = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
  console.log(currentCard);
}
```

---

So this is what the console logged:

heart
 
club
 
heart
 
heart
 
heart
 
spade

Every time I log the console the 'spade' appears and the idea is the console not to log 'spade'.

I hope someone can help me out here and happy coding for everyone.

Comment: Unless you use `break;` somewhere in your loop, it will always finish the current iteration before checking the condition again. If you don't want to log "spade", insert `if (currentCard == "spade") break;` right after randomly picking one.

Comment: You select the card and immediately log it before the the check can happen.

Comment: Flow chart: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-i1W59d7B8R4/T3izXShRgHI/AAAAAAAAAFI/OcmcydxcZV0/s1600/while.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop condition is checked at the start of the loop, not during it.

Try this instead to not see any "spade" in console:

```
const cards = ['diamond', 'spade', 'heart', 'club'];

// Write your code below
let currentCard;

currentCard = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];

while ( currentCard != 'spade') {
  console.log(currentCard);
  //Assigning a new value AFTER the console.log assures it will be
  //checked against the while condition before console.log hits again
  currentCard = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
}
```

Comment: Again, I feel it should be pointed out that duplicating that assignment is unnecessary (and a violation of DRY) since one can simply `break` out of the loop.